# Get property from attribute value

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Having this simple class:

```
public class Book
{
    [DataMember]
    [Column("Bok_Name")]
    [Author("AuthorName")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Column("Bok_Publisher")]
    public string Publisher{ get; set; }
}
```

How can i can get the PropertyInfo from a property knowing that the attribute type is Column and the value is Bok_Name. I has trying to do this with a linq query.

Comment: I didn't get your question? What are you trying to get? Can you post any example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I think first, access all the properties and their attributes , then compare the attributes with what you want

Comment: @Ehsan. Something like PropertyInfo pInfo = t.GetProperties().Where(a => a.GetCustomAttribute(ColumnAttribute).Value == "Bok_Name");.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using reflection and the .NET extension [CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute{T}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194292(v=vs.110).aspx) method, you can find the properties with the custom attribute. In this case, the custom attribute is from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.ColumnAttribute`.

```
var book = new Book { Name = "Jitterbug Perfume" };

PropertyInfo bokName = typeof(Book)
    .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance) // add other bindings if needed
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>() != null
       && x.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>().Name.Equals("Bok_Name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

// the above query only gets the first property with Column attribute equal to "Bok_Name"
// if there are more than one, then use a .Where clause instead of FirstOrDefault.
if (bokName != null)
{
    string name = bokName.GetValue(book).ToString();
    // do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    var type = typeof (Book); //or var type=instance.GetType();

    var res=type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(
            p =>
                (p.GetCustomAttribute<ColumnAttribute>() ?? new ColumnAttribute()).Value == "Bok_Name");
```

Comment: One should also note that `GetCustomAttribute` is an extension method, so you need to add `using System.Reflection;` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

In the piggy bank, variant on VB NET:

```
Dim maxLength = ValToInt(document.GetDataAnnotationPropertyAttributeValue(fieldName, GetType(MaxLengthAttribute)))
    
Public Function GetDataAnnotationPropertyAttributeValue(propertyName As String, attributeType As Type) As Object
            Dim properties = Me.GetType().GetProperties()
            Dim propertyInfo = properties.FirstOrDefault(Function(p) p.Name?.ToLower() = propertyName?.ToLower())
            If propertyInfo Is Nothing Then Return Nothing
    
            Dim attribute = propertyInfo.CustomAttributes.FirstOrDefault(Function(a) a.AttributeType.Equals(attributeType))
            Return attribute?.ConstructorArguments(0).Value
End Function
```

Comment: But this question is for C#

Comment: Ok, sry. I was looking for a solution on VB.Net, this article helped me, so I left my version here. Because the VB.Net community is too small. Hope this helps someone like me.

Comment: In scenarios like that, it makes sense to post a new question for VB, then answer your own question.